# What is the increase in drag by adding a space station module?

Tags: orbit, atmosphere, space-station

Imagine a cylindrical space station module, orbiting at an arbitrary height - the same as the ISS say.

Another identity cylindrical module docks on the end.  Real station cross section hasn't changed - the same surface area is pointing in the direction of travel.

How does this effect the total drag caused by the atmosphere?  If zero impact, what if we add a third?  A fourth?  A fifth?

At what point would we materially change the drag experienced?

Comment: You'll get some skin friction drag from the new section, but at that altitude air density is very small---just 6.017e-12 kg/m3---so even though you're moving at ~8 km/s, and drag is proportional to the square of velocity, you're still looking at drag forces 3 to 4 orders of magnitude smaller than you'd get at sea level (~1 kg/m3) moving at 1 m/s. Plus, friction drag is just one component of the whole drag force, which includes also form drag, and I don't think that would change if your cross-sectional area hasn't changed? Either way, the effects would be measurable only on long time scales.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drag is proportional to the cross-sectional area. If you don't change that and keep the other parameters (coefficent, air density, velocity) the same, the drag will not change.

https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/drageq.html

What you *will* change is the ballistic coefficient, which is proportional to mass.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_coefficient

Comment: In dense air, at least, changing the proportions of a body while leaving its cross-section the same does change its drag coefficient (due to increased skin drag, if nothing else). I don't know if this holds for near-vacuum and v = 7700m/s, though.

Comment: @RussellBorogove It's at least, a strong function of the windward area  "One of the more complex tasks in determining the coefficient of drag is the
development of an accurate model for the cross-sectional area of a spacecraft"  https://etda.libraries.psu.edu/files/final_submissions/9285

Comment: This is interesting. I think skin drag in the [molecular flow regime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_molecular_flow) will need its own question.

Comment: This is interesting. I think skin drag in the [molecular flow regime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_molecular_flow) will need its own question. Speed of 1200 K monatomic oxygen molecules at 400 km in the [thermosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermosphere#Neutral_gas_constituents) is about 1000 m/s so they will be hitting the sides of a long skinny rocket-shaped space station and so will cause some drag, but while we don't yet know how much, we can't say there's no effect.

Comment: @uhoh I can say there's no *significant* effect. https://imgflip.com/s/meme/Change-My-Mind.jpg

Comment: So the conclusion appears to be there will be some, but it's going to be nearly nothing and we can't determine the answer?

Comment: @OrganicMarble The question starts out by doubling the length of a new station, I have no idea, but if each module has a 5:1 aspect ratio, and we're comparing 1 vs 2 modules, I'll bet the increase in drag by adding the 2nd module is *at least a percent.* I don't need to change your mind because you've change it already; from "will not change" to "no *significant* effect". $$\frac{\text{small}}{\text{none}} = \infty$$

Comment: @user2702772 I think it will change a little, but not a huge amount. If you double the mass the rate of orbit decay will slow by half, but it will take twice as much fuel to bring it back.

Comment: I was thinking of the extreme cases though.  Imagine a ring of modules around a planet...